# Acumatica: Limit export scenario records by current date

Tags: c#, acumatica

Is there any way that I can limit the results given by an export scenario to only those that have a date matching the current date? It's possible in Generic Inquiries, but I don't see any way to do it in an export scenario. It allows you to apply a source restriction for the date, but you have to hardcode a value. You can't give it a value like "@Today" or "Today()"

I can build a customization if that's needed.

[image]

Comment: Post your code, we cant help without it

Comment: It's not code. You build an export scenario through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I add a datediff using datelastmodified to the GI so I can filter by days since last modified.

Of course would work for datecreated or creating a isToday field.

Another option is to filter the GI itself if it's only used for this Export.